# Can we send the reward of recitation of Quran or other ibadah to relatives who died?

Tags: quran, hadith, death, uloom-al-hadith, ibadah

A lot of people  recite Quran and perform other ibadah and pray that the reward of this ibadah be given to a relative or friend who died.

What Quranic verses or Hadith tells us that the reward of one person's ibadah can be sent/given/gifted to another dead person?

Please also quote reference of Quranic verse or Hadith you mention.

Thank you for enlightening me in advance. Jazak Allah

Answer (score 1):

All Praise to Allah Subhanahu wa Taala and blessings of Him be on Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him His family and companions,

Yeah we could ask Allah Swt to send the rewards to the deceased ones by the recitation of Quran or some other kind of rewardful acts,here are some  references,

> 'Abdullah bin Abu Qatadah narrated that his father said: "The
>   Messenger of Allah said: 'The best things that a man can leave behind
>   are three: A righteous son who will pray for him, ongoing charity
>   whose reward will reach him, and knowledge which is acted upon after
>   his death.'" (Hasan) Another chain with similar wording.(Ibn Majah)

and

> Narrated Ibn `Abbas: A man said to Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) , "My mother
>   died, will it benefit her if I give in charity on her behalf?" The
>   Prophet (ﷺ) replied in the affirmative. The man said, "I have a garden
>   and I make you a witness that I give it in charity on her
>   behalf."(Bukhari)

And

> It was narrated from Abu Hurairah that a man asked the Messenger of
>   Allah (ﷺ): “My father died and left behind wealth, but he did not make
>   a will. Will it expiate for him if I give charity on his behalf?” He
>   said: “Yes.”(Ibn Majah)

and

> It was narrated from Ma’qil bin Yasar that the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ)
>   said: “Recite Qur’an near your dying ones,” meaning Ya-Sin.(Ibn Majah)

**And [there is a share for] those who came after them, saying, "Our Lord, forgive us and our brothers who preceded us in faith and put not in our hearts [any] resentment toward those who have believed. Our Lord, indeed You are Kind and Merciful."(Quran 59:10)**

Allah Swt and His Messenger knows best.